# pandas df.replace() not working properly mapping state abbreviations to full name using python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a python dictionary that looks like this:

```
states = {
        'AK': 'Alaska',
        'AL': 'Alabama',
        'AR': 'Arkansas',
        'AS': 'American Samoa',
        'AZ': 'Arizona',
        'CA': 'California'...}
```

for all states and territories in the US.

My Dataframe looks something like this [pandas data frame.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrVxs.png)

I've tried code like:

```
df['state'].replace(states)
```

and

`df['state'].map(states)`

but both do not work.

edit: suggestions to set the Series equal to the code above didn't work, the Dataframe remains the same with 2 letter abbreviations.

Comment: `df['state] = df['state'].replace(states)`

Comment: You either need to assign the result, or use `inplace=True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `df['state']` has spurious spaces preventing the dict keys from matching. Try stripping (`str.strip`) before replacing:

```
df['state'] = df['state'].str.strip().replace(states)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to write:

```
df['state'] = = df['state'].replace(states)
```

Or alternatively

```
df['state'].replace(states, inplace=True)
```

Both make sure that you actually change the series in question, rather than just making a new series with the changes.

Comment: I was using juypter notebook so I thought I could get around the inplace argument just to see the end result first. Even with the inplace argument, the end result is still just the two letter abbreviations.